# Accessing infobright from Java

Tags: java, jdbc, olap, infobright

Would someone advise me technology for accessing Infobright from java. 
As far as I understand I should use plain jdbc connection and execute queries, not making use of high level thing like hibernate. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Infobright from Java would be the same approach as you would with MySQL. We support the JDBC drivers that are available from the MySQL website.

Comment: Thanks! And what about hibernate here ??

Comment: @Andrew You can set up a JDBC connection in the Hibernate configuration the same way you would if it was MySQL. Keep in mind that 'UPDATE' performance is relatively poor in Infobright, however.